# Bash: Dynamically create environment variables

Tags: bash, azure-devops, devops

We're delivering secrets into our containers via a path, e.g.:  /mnt/secrets

...and each subsequent file in that directory is the 'secret' with the contents being the value:  e.g.  /mnt/secrets/somepassword contains 'superdooperpassword123'

This is happening because we're managing our secrets from a secret-store provider (encrypted, etc.).  However, I need to convert those files+filecontents to environment variables to be used in other scripts.

Here is the script I attempted to use to accomplish that, secrets.sh:

```
FILES="/mnt/secrets/*"
for f in $FILES
do
  FILE=$(basename $f)
  echo "Creating environment variable for the following secret:  $FILE"
  declare -xg $(echo $FILE)=$(cat $f)
done
```

And while this runs without error, I don't see (via 'set' or get nothing with 'echo $var') when I try to ensure they're available.  I've tried multiple arguments for 'declare' but I can't seem to expose the declared variables running in secrets.sh (from the files and their contents) back to bash.

I know I'm probably missing something simple.  Any assistance would be appreciate to direct me how to use a shell script that reads files and their contents from the filesystem into dynamically created environment variables.  TIA!~

Comment: Don't use `$(echo $FILE)` -- it's an elaborate and error-prone way to do `$FILE`, because the `$( )` and `echo` mostly cancel each other out.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, so how would you handle if the filename (that will end up as the var name) has hyphens in it that need to be swapped for underscores?  I've presently modified to:  declare -xg $(echo $FILE | tr '-' '_')=$(cat $f)  -- NOTE:  what I've posted is working for the 20(ish) secrets we're loading into our containers...

Comment: nm... if i need to, i can move it up into the $FILE var creation line.

Comment: Using `echo` this way to feed a pipe is ok, but for a simple substitution like this I'd use `${FILE//-/_}="$(cat $f)"` (but note that this type of substitution is a bashism, and won't work in some more basic shells like dash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to source the file

```
source secrets.sh
```

or

```
. secrets.sh
```

otherwise you are setting the variables of the child process which are not the same as the parent's